# Optional capture always ignored in favor of *

Tags: regex

Given the statement

`the cat and the dog played together`

I can capture both cat and dog with this regex

```
(cat).*(dog)
```

There will not always be a cat in the sentence, so I make the first capture group optional

```
(cat)?.*(dog)
```

**When using an optional capture group the `.*` always grabs the entire first part ignoring the optional capture even though it is there. How can cat be grabbed if it is there, but if it is absent the regex will still match dog?**

I have tried making the star non-greedy

```
(cat)?.*?(dog)
```

and have tried using `|` instead of an optional capture group, yet the first capture group always gets ignored.

Sample result, http://regex101.com/r/pR1kZ9

Comment: something like this? http://regex101.com/r/eB7hD8

Comment: Post it as an anaswer, not a comment.

Comment: @abc123 - the matches that generates are `cat and the `, `_and the_`, `dog`. That's not `cat`,`dog`. (sorry about the underscores - they represent spaces)

Comment: @anubhava - I think we need your help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?:(cat).*)?(dog)
```

Matches 'cat' and subsequent characters up to next 'dog' as a single, non-capturing group, but captures the 'cat'.

Demo at http://regex101.com/r/cE9yC8

Sample:

```
the cat and the dog played together  - match 'cat' and 'dog
the mouse didn't play with the dog   - match 'dog'
```

Comment: It did in the examples I tried, don't know why it wouldn't "seem" to, but in software a failing test case is always appreciated.

Comment: It didn't "seem" to when I pasted your solution into the demo link in the original question and added a line without cat. It turns out that it works fine when you include the `g` flag, or when the 'cat'less phrase is the only one there. I edited your answer to demonstrate it is correct, and so that I could upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I found one:

```
(?:.*?(?=cat))?(cat)?.*(dog)
```

Match everything up to the word cat; then match cat if it's there, then match anything up to dog.

```
the cat played with the dog    ==> 'cat', 'dog'
the mouse played with the dog  ==> 'dog'
the dog played with the cat    ==> 'dog'
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/eT7pR4

Comment: Why does the look behind make this work? Because the look behind affects the first `.*` but then after that it's the same as my original regex.

Comment: @Despertar - it is a lookahead. So it tries to "consume everything up to (but not including) `cat`; and after that, it "notices" that `cat` is there to be matched, I suppose. I agree that it is strange that your solution didn't work to begin with.